# JDBC seems to be putting single quotes around my numbers

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I understand that best practice in SQL is to not use single quotes around numeric values to avoid having them converted to Strings.  However, when I use a PreparedStatement in JDBC and then ask to see the statement, single quotes are placed around all values that I set, numbers included.  In the below example I am sending in three lists - a list of column names as Strings, a list of datatypes as Strings and a list of values as Strings.  When the datatype is "int", I am converting the value to an integer and using setInt() into the statement, otherwise I am using setString().  However, the println of the PreparedStatement.toString() results in single quotes surrounding anything that I used setInt() on.

```
  public void update(String tableName, String colName, String valName, List<String> columnList, List<String> typeList, List<String> valueList) {
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
      String setterSet = columnList.get(0) + "=?";
      for (int cCol = 1; cCol < columnList.size(); cCol++) {
        setterSet += "," + columnList.get(cCol) + "=?";
      }
      stmt = theConnection.prepareStatement("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " + setterSet + " WHERE " + colName + " = ?;");
      for (int cCol = 1; cCol <= valueList.size(); cCol++) {
        if (typeList.get(cCol - 1).equals("int")) {
          stmt.setInt(cCol, Integer.parseInt(valueList.get(cCol - 1)));
        }
        else {
          stmt.setString(cCol, valueList.get(cCol - 1));
        }
      }
      stmt.setString(valueList.size() + 1, valName);
      System.out.println("Prepared Statement: " + stmt.toString());
      int rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
      stmt.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Problem with the database: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

The standard out print looks like this:

```
Prepared Statement: UPDATE data_sources SET id_='e80c861c-bf6c-4300-80e0-3eab29e06cec',ds_name='test001',num_files='75' WHERE ds_name = 'test001'
```

Is it usual that the 75 is quoted?

Edit: to clarify, I'm using PostgreSQL and my JDBC driver is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>8.4-702.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't if it is usual but it makes no difference

Comment: The specific behaviour of `PreparedStatement#toString()` is implementation-dependent. If you want something more than just guesses you should [edit] your question to mention (and tag) what JDBC driver you are using.

Comment: Did you check if that is also what is being sent to the server? I would guess this is just a naive implementation of the `toString()` method to show _some_ information - but not the exact data that is sent to the server.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, the server seems to be getting updated correctly, so this was more of a curiosity as to what the real best practice is.  I suspect you are right about the toString implementation.

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you using such an outdated driver version?

Comment: FWIW, I just tried a simple test with postgresql-42.0.0.jar and numbers were not quoted in `toString()` output: `UPDATE public.user SET age=56 WHERE id=2`

Answer (score 1):

This is just informational. If you call `toString()` on a PostgreSQL instance of `PreparedStatement`, it will simply render the query with the current parameter values. It is just informational (eg for logging), and is not how the query is sent to the server.

See:

- [`PgPreparedStatement.toString()`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgPreparedStatement.java#L978)

  > Returns the SQL statement with the current template values substituted.
- [`Query.toString(ParameterList parameters)`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/Query.java#L40)

  > Stringize this query to a human-readable form, substituting particular parameter values for parameter placeholders.

This is driver-specific behavior, because some implementations will only return the statement string that was prepared, while other implementations will return the default `Object.toString()`.

Sidenote: you are using a pretty old version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver, note that [the driver version is not related to the server version](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/faq.html#versioning). So if for some reason you are still on PostgreSQL 8.4, you can still use the latest driver (42.0.0) which supports PostgreSQL 8.2 and higher.